# Using New Relic with Docker Cloud

Tags: docker

Ok, so here is the setup.

We are using docker cloud in "bring your own node" configuration. Our node is running Ubuntu 14.04.

We have installed `dockercloud-agent` and `nrsysmond` as required by the respective tutorials. The New Relic agent is reporting data, and we can deploy oour stack through docker cloud, so clearly both are working.

However, New Relic is not reporting docker container metrics. I found a document suggesting that this might be that "older" operating systems may store their cgroup files in "non-default locations".

Unfortunately I don't have a clue what older means in this context, or whether `/sys/fs/cgroup/devices/docker` is a "non-default" location, or if it is, what to put in the `cgroup_root` field  in the New Relic configuration file.

Has anyone gotten any of this to work?

Comment: did you get this to work in the end?

Comment: No. I stopped using Docker Cloud.It doesn't really do what we wanted to do anyway.